# Silverlight 4.0 Click on hidden object

Tags: c#, silverlight

I have a hidden image

```xml
<Image x:Name="abc" MouseLeftButtonDown="Handler" Visibility="Collapsed" .../>
```

I've provided a handler function:

```
private void Handler(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
{

}
```

By my handler never fires. How can I listen to a handler for my hidden image?

Answer (score 2):

If you want to be able to click on an `Image` that isn't visible (though I have no idea why you would want to do so), try using `Opacity="0"` instead of `Visibility="Collapsed"`.

A control that has a Visibility of `Collapsed` isn't hidden, it's completely removed from the screen.  It's impossible to click on a `Collapsed` object because it takes up no space on the screen.

Answer (score 1):

How can you click on something that is collapsed?

You could wrap the image in a grid with a transparent color, collapse the image and register for the click on the grid.